# Leer texto cuando el cursor esté sobre un botón - Accesibilidad

Tags: html, css, accesibilidad

Estoy tratando de que cuando el cursor esté sobre un botón de HTML, un lector de pantalla (como NVDA) pueda leer la descripción del botón.

Ya intenté con aria-label, pero este atributo sólo lo reconoce el lector de pantalla cuando está en foco (cuando se selecciona o se navega con las flechas del teclado o con tab) y efectivamente lee el texto de aria-label, pero nocuando el cursor está sobre el botón.

Esto lo pregunto porque me topé con esta problemática principalmente con los botones con iconos, ya que al pasar el cursor no lee alguna descripción del ratón, aunque le ponga aria-label, aria-labelledby o aria-describbedby.

Muchas gracias por sus respuestas de antemano.

Comment: Hola. Yo estoy ahora mismo probando un *screen reader*. A ver, desde mi ignorancia, en realidad si no ves o ves poco el ratón no tiene mucho sentido... como para versiones móbiles de la web. Los screen readers van recorriendo los diferentes elementos de la página, entonces solo "leen" el elemento donde esta el foco. Mira este video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LnvAGDN6TVA

Comment: Así es, pero el lector de pantalla no sólo lo usan personas ciegas, sino también personas con baja visión que lo emplean como un apoyo para leer o reconocer elementos. Es por ello que lectores como NVDA tienen el Modo de Seguimiento del Ratón configurado.

Comment: @Franco_Salvador_Hernndez_Hernn es bueno saberlo. No te olvides a aportar una respuesta si la encuentras en otra parte.

Answer (score 0):

¡Ya encontré la respuesta! Al final sí es con WAI, pero tenemos que definir más atributos además de `aria-label`. Puesto que es un icono, debemos asegurarnos que el lector no lo omita, así que definimos `aria-hidden="false"`. Por último, al ser un icono, ya sea con Font Awesome o cualquier otro tipo de icono, debemos establecerle el rol de imagen con `role="img"`, de esta forma, el lector de pantalla tomará el `aria-label` como la descripción de una imagen común y corriente y leerá el `aria-label` incluso si situamos el cursor sobre el icono y sin tener que navegar con el teclado.

¡Gracias!
Saludos.